# Keyboard layout indicator sometimes disappears Ubuntu 18.04.1 after some update

Tags: 18.04, gnome, keyboard-layout, indicator, extension

Ubuntu 18.04.1, GNOME 3.28.2, Tweaks -> Extension: Dash to panel

After some updates 05 Jan 2019 - 08 Jan 2019 I began to see sometimes:

Unstable:
[image: Language Panel after]

(But this is **NOT permanent**! For example i made screenshot from normal behavior. + **Same troubles on login screen** which reduces the extensions effect!)

Stable: 
[image: Language Panel before]

Simple temporary fix - is select language with mouse cursor or twice with keyboard hotkeys.

Comment: the same issue. Really annoying thing

Answer (score 6):

It is not linked with Extension. I have same problem and no extensions installed at all.

Also when indicator disappear, clicking "Show Keyboard Layout" is not working at all

Switching with keyboard or mouse will fix problem.

Problem is there only on restore after sleep, never after fresh boot. Also happen after locking/coming from lock screen.

Comment: In my case I must twice switch keyboard layout!. For example, when I login Ubuntu I must switch layout first time to see indicator with my non-latin (regional) layout, then second to switch to latin. And now i can type password for account.