# Keyboard Layout indicator doesn't display current layout in Ubuntu 18.04 (empty drop down box)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, indicator, gnome-shell

I see an empty drop down box where the language code of the [current keyboard layout](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/keyboard-layout.html.en) should be.

**To reproduce the bug**: Lock screen or log out and log in again.

[image: screenshot of keyboard layout indicator on gnome shell]

I also get the same behavior on the lock screen at the time when I try to log in with my password:

[image: screenshot of keyboard layout indicator on gdm]

After I tried the workaround (below) the language code on the login screen disappeared as soon as I typed the first character of my password.

**Workaround** (not permanent): Switching with keyboard (<kbd>Super+space</kbd>) or mouse.

**System info**: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, GNOME 3.28.2.

[image: system info]

Please [indicate in the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1812266) if also affects you.

Comment: Its start happens after some this year update. No fiddling with the keyboard settings were made.

Comment: Yes, it was my post. Just switch to OFF all extensions with one single switcher (in GNOME Tweaks Title), Reboot, but get same indicator behavior.. Perhaps it is worth trying to disable all GNOME Tweaks, but I'm not sure that's 100% possible now.

Comment: Is `~/.config/dconf/user` writable and owned by you?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson yes, -rw-r--r-- and my owner and group.

Comment: Ok. As an experiment you may want to rename that file and relogin. If that would not help, you can just rename it back to its original name.

Comment: Trying: `mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user_back` then reboot. At first glance, everything was fine, new file `~/.config/dconf/user` auto-created by OS.. But after a few hours problem returned.

Comment: Not seems a dconf issue: From "" (empty) to "en" (or any) doesn't change anything on database (checked with `dconf dump / > test`). Switching language modify `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources`. Maybe related to [this old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/531173). @mature To help search engines could you replace the system info screenshot with the output of `inxi -SG -! 31`? And [why this duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108289/keyboard-layout-indicator-sometimes-disappears-ubuntu-18-04-1-after-last-update)?

Comment: Not sure if related: Not only the current layout indicator change after a lock but **the whole indicator area** (with gnome extensions disabled): [screenshots of before/after](https://i.imgur.com/OazRcHL.png). #workaround: [Restart Gnome Shell: Alt+F2 r](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet#Developer_tools). This happen to you too?

Comment: Will be [fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1812266/comments/13) in `gnome-shell - 3.30.2-2ubuntu1`

Comment: The keyboard layout indicator problem has been fixed by a recent update in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[A fix was released](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1812266), already verified on Cosmic and Bionic.

#### EnableProposed

Until is added to normal repos, to enable them on Bionic (18.04) as said [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1812266/comments/37), follow [these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed) to enable the proposed archive, which basically say:

1. Enable pre-release updates: [image: emphasized text]
2. Add to `/etc/apt/preferences.d/proposed-updates`

   ```
   Package: *
   Pin: release a=bionic-proposed
   Pin-Priority: 400
   ```

   If `sudo apt-get upgrade -s` return any package, something went wrong.
3. Run `sudo aptitude -t bionic-proposed`
4. [Update with <kbd>u</kbd>](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_key_bindings_of_aptitude)
5. Select the proposed related packages:

   - gnome-shell-common 3.28.3+git20190124-0ubuntu18.04.1
   - gnome-shell 3.28.3+git20190124-0ubuntu18.04.1
6. Upgrade with <kbd>g</kbd>
7. [Restart GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/a/1113598/349837).

Please test it and eventually suggest changes to this post. If everything went OK upvote and share your love with the developers.

Comment: Could someone with the mad skills be so kind as to post an actual workaround for this annoying as hell problem that doesn't involve grabbing all proposed fixes (I just want my keyboard layout indicator back!).

Comment: It seems a [fix was released](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1812266) recently.

Answer (score 2):

After some January updates got the same problem, but on Ubuntu 18.10. 
Reinstalling appindicator packages (see commands below), somehow partially fixed the problem: lang indicator stop disappearing in gnome-shell, but still do in gdm.

```
apt install --reinstall gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1
apt install --reinstall gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
```

#### Update 2019-01-20

the commands above didn't work. worked solution, at least for ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic), is rollback to previous version of `gnome-shell` and `gnome-shell-common` packages:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-shell=3.30.1-2ubuntu1 gnome-shell-common=3.30.1-2ubuntu1
```

and perform the reboot

optionally, but highly recommend - prevent update on those packages, like these:

```
sudo apt-mark hold gnome-shell gnome-shell-common
```

and wait for fix. after fix will be released - just `unhold` those packages and run update\upgrade command.

#### for ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)

you should try rollback those packages to `3.28.1-0ubuntu2` version.

#### possible origin of the problem

the only difference between old version and version at January update is in [this bugfix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1765304); he also relate to ibus, so that fix may be the cause of the "disappearing lang indicator" problem

Comment: Thanks. Trying. But, isn't fix in my case.

Comment: rollback `gnome-shell` and `gnome-shell-common` 
- from version 3.30.1-2ubuntu1.18.10.2 
- to version 3.30.1-2ubuntu1 
on ubuntu cosmic (18.10) completly fix the problem.

I think on 18.04 rollback those packages 
- from 3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 
- to 3.28.1-0ubuntu2 should do the same thing.

Comment: according to page on launchpad ( https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell ). Only difference between versions is this bugfix - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1765304 think problem in that fix.