# Is there any 3rd party keyboard layout indicator software for GNOME?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-gnome

Looking any another Ubuntu Gnome Shell Keyboard Layout Indicator.

Comment: Did you search on [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/)? What's wrong with default one?

Comment: Default isn't work correctly https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109555/keyboard-layout-indicator-dont-display-current-layout-in-ubuntu-18-04-empty-dro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Founded excellent solution but looks like just for `En`/`Ru` keyboard layouts and product just in sources. But I think this idea is more than brilliant: The idea is to add a keyboard layout flag to the mouse cursor.

Software name: **X Cursor Flag**

Screenshot:

[image: X Cursor Flag Desktop]