# Lanuage suddenly missing - ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I have two input keyboard layouts English and Greek.

Sometimes after I change once or twice and usually when I try to put a password for authentication purposes, I put on the password, it returns false and when I check the Language sign on upper right side, the sign is totally empty without any 'en' or 'gr' totally blank(only the arrow next to it appears.

When I hit the buttons I've set for the language switch both languages come back again, it's like when in idle or energy save mode that it loses it again.

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1121203/28667

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug and it is tracked [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1812266). It has been fixed but at the moment the fix is not in main repositories.

**For Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic)**: the problem should be resolved when `gnome-shell` is updated to version 3.30.2-2.

**For Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)**: the fix is still under review ([more information](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1812266))

You can the following command to check the installed version of `gnome-shell` package:

```
apt-cache policy gnome-shell
```